# Debian : MPI code - Intel compiler - [Hardware Error]: Unified Memory Controller Error: DRAM ECC error

Tags: debian, intel, amd, compiler, mpi

When running an executable compiled with `intel mpiicc`, I get, after 30 minutes of running, the
following errors :

```
 kernel:[29585.573874] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.

Message from syslogd@pablo at Nov  8 09:53:25 ...
 kernel:[29585.573881] [Hardware Error]: CPU:2 (17:31:0) MC18_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|AddrV|-|-|SyndV|-|CECC]: 0xdc2041000000011b

Message from syslogd@pablo at Nov  8 09:53:25 ...
 kernel:[29585.573887] [Hardware Error]: Error Addr: 0x0000000a6c12d280

Message from syslogd@pablo at Nov  8 09:53:25 ...
 kernel:[29585.573888] [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x0000009600550f00, Syndrome: 0xc54c00040a800611

Message from syslogd@pablo at Nov  8 09:53:25 ...
 kernel:[29585.573891] [Hardware Error]: Unified Memory Controller Extended Error Code: 0

Message from syslogd@pablo at Nov  8 09:53:25 ...
 kernel:[29585.573893] [Hardware Error]: Unified Memory Controller Error: DRAM ECC error.

Message from syslogd@pablo at Nov  8 09:53:25 ...
 kernel:[29585.573895] [Hardware Error]: cache level: L3/GEN, tx: GEN, mem-tx: RD
```

I am working on a `AMD EPYC 7702P 64-Core Processor` with 1TB of RAM and a Debian OS :

```
Linux pablo 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From what I have seen, I did the command : `dmidecode -t memory` that gives :

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 2 TB
    Error Information Handle: 0x0022
    Number Of Devices: 8

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0023
    Error Information Handle: 0x002A
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 128 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered) LRDIMM
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 03C6F701
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M386AAG40MMB-CVF
    Rank: 4
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0xCE
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 128 kB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0023
    Error Information Handle: 0x002D
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 128 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered) LRDIMM
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 03C6F3ED
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M386AAG40MMB-CVF
    Rank: 4
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0xCE
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 128 kB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0023
    Error Information Handle: 0x0030
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 128 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL C
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered) LRDIMM
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 03C6F4BA
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M386AAG40MMB-CVF
    Rank: 4
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0xCE
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 128 kB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0023
    Error Information Handle: 0x0033
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 128 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL D
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered) LRDIMM
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 03C6F396
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M386AAG40MMB-CVF
    Rank: 4
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0xCE
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 128 kB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0023
    Error Information Handle: 0x0036
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 128 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL E
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered) LRDIMM
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 03C6F67D
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M386AAG40MMB-CVF
    Rank: 4
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0xCE
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 128 kB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0023
    Error Information Handle: 0x0039
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 128 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL F
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered) LRDIMM
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 03C6F394
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M386AAG40MMB-CVF
    Rank: 4
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0xCE
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 128 kB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0023
    Error Information Handle: 0x003C
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 128 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL G
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered) LRDIMM
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 03C6F48A
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M386AAG40MMB-CVF
    Rank: 4
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0xCE
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 128 kB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0040, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0023
    Error Information Handle: 0x003F
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 128 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL H
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered) LRDIMM
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 03C6F3FB
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M386AAG40MMB-CVF
    Rank: 4
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Unknown
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 1, Hex 0xCE
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 128 kB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None
```

I don't know where these `DRAM ECC error` come from, Maybe there are incompatibilies between my motherboard, CPU model or bad version of `Intel compiler SDK` ?

These errors appears roughly every 5 minutes during the execution.

I am using the intel compilers version `compilers_and_libraries_2020.1.217`.

**I have also the same error messages when I compile with MPI from official Open-MPI Debian 10 repository version.**

I should modify maybe an option in the BIOS but I am not sure.

If someone had an idea to solve this issue, this would be fine to tell it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your ram is faulty, it is a hardware problrm. I suggest you to either run memtest for a long time or change the sticks and try your application again. Probably the application allocates too much ram accessing the faulty sectors.